Material that Increases Angle of Incoming Light
Snell's law states that light refracts when entering a substance and refracts back to its original angle upon exit. This is shown in the diagram below from this webpage.

I was wondering if there are materials or optical devices that increase the angle of light upon entry and maintain that increased angle upon exit, i.e. $\theta_3 > \theta_1$. Lenses do this, but I am interested in cases where shifts to incoming light are only dependent on the angle of incidence, not the position of incidence.

I might be wrong but you can probably prove such a material can't exist because the system should be reversible.

You may be looking for a prism. Entrance & exit faces non-parallel.

@Triatticus a non-reciprocal optical medium #2 is just that, nonreciprocal in the sense that it behaves differently depending on the direction of the ray, formally $n_2(\mathbf k) \ne n_2(-\mathbf k)$, see Faraday effect. It does need a magnetic bias field, though, and is widely used even in the 1GHz-100GHz range there is a multi $MM business, "microwave ferrites" based on it.

Yeah I should have included passive medium, but I don't remember the faraday effect doing that since what it normally produces a change in the phases of the waves. But as I said I might be wrong since I haven't done anything with optics in a long time.
